# SpringBoot @OneToMany infinite loop with Lombok

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, hibernate

My project using SpringBoot, it has bidirectional mapping @OneToMany

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_S")
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
    public class S implements Serializable {
        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
        @JoinColumn(name = "something", referencedColumnName = "A_ID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
        @OptimisticLock(excluded = false)
        private Set<A> act = new HashSet<>();
        ....something...
    }

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "T_A")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @EqualsAndHashCode
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @ToString
    public class A{
        @ManyToOne(optional = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "A_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
        private S sub;
    }
```

whe i get data from repository it make infinitive loop. How to fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use @ToString.Exclude on that attribute which makes an infinite loop.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_S")
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class S implements Serializable {
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "something", referencedColumnName = "A_ID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @OptimisticLock(excluded = false)
    private Set<A> act = new HashSet<>();
        ....something...
}



@Entity
@Table(name = "T_A")
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class A{
    @ToString.Exclude -----------------> here is the change
    @ManyToOne(optional = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "A_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private S sub;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have bidirectional relationships Lombok equals,
hashCode and toString will create a StackOverflowError.

So remove @ToString and @EqualsAndHashCode.

I'm general equals and hashCode should be implemented on a unique business key when using JPA.

Another way would be to exclude certain attributes from Lombok.

Comment: i think this is good solution or we can @overide two method

Answer (score 1):

Note that your code is including the collections and relationships in the `toString()` method. When you *print* any *S* instance, Java try to include the data for the related *A* instances and then, for each of them, try to include the data of the original *S*.

You must consider to exclude these collections from the `toString()` method in one of these classes or in both of them.

### How to exclude collections from the `toString()` method

In Lombok you may define which columns and relationships include into the `toString()` method:

- [`@ToString`](https://projectlombok.org/features/ToString), by default, includes all the non-static fields in the `toString()` method.
- To exclude any field, you may annotate it with `@ToString.Exclude`
- Alternatively, you may annotate the class with `@ToString(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)` and mark the filed that wanna include with `@ToString.Include`.

For instance, in the class *S* you may exclude the collection of *A* by annotating it using `@ToString.Exclude`:

```
@ToString
public class S {


    @ToString.Exclude
    private Set<A> act = new HashSet<>();

}
```

Please note that, when you include a lazy-load collection in the `toString()`, JPA will load all the related instances when you print any instance. You must annotate all the lazy-load collections with `@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude` and `@ToString.Exclude`. In fact, many authors recommend to avoid the generation of `hashCode()` and `equals()` method for JPA entities with Lombok.

### Fixing your code

I recommend to exclude the collections from the `toString()` of both classes, to avoid the load of the lazy-load relationships. In addition, do not use Lombok to generate `equals()` and `hashCode()` and follow a guide for [implementing `equals()` and `hashcode()` for JPA entities](https://thorben-janssen.com/ultimate-guide-to-implementing-equals-and-hashcode-with-hibernate/).

```
@Entity
@ToString
// Do not use @EqualsAndHashCode in JPA entities
  :
public class S {

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
     :
    @ToString.Exclude   // exclude lazy-load relationships
    private Set<A> act = new HashSet<>();

     :
}


@Entity
@ToString
// Do not use @EqualsAndHashCode in JPA entities
  :
public class A{

    @ManyToOne(optional = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
      :
    @ToString.Exclude // exclude lazy load relationships
    private S sub;
}
```

### Other considerations using Lombok with JPA

There are many potential problems when you use Lombok and JPA in the same classes. For instance, the `hashCode()` method may not work with entities with auto-generated identifiers, the `equals()` may include unwanted fields and the `toString()` method may force to load the lazy-load relationships and produce infinite loops.

To avoid these problems, you may check some guides from [Thorben Janssen](https://thorben-janssen.com/lombok-hibernate-how-to-avoid-common-pitfalls/) and [JPA Buddy](https://www.jpa-buddy.com/blog/lombok-and-jpa-what-may-go-wrong/).

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer only mentions `@ToString` (that generates the `toString` method) but the `@EqualsAndHashCode` also can trigger infinite loops with JPA and lombok (with `equals` and `hashCode` respectively).

As @Simon Martinelli said in his answer, this is due to the bidirectional relationship (parent and child entities both have a reference to each other) so the lombok code generated by the `toString` and `hashCode` methods both call each other forever (in my case my memory settings were so high that the code would just freeze so it was even harder to diagnose since I didn't get the usual StackOverflowError).

Simon said to remove these, but in my opinion we should still be able to keep the generated `toString` and `hashCode`; so the best solution i found was to exclude the reference in the non-owning side. Hence, if the parent is the owning side:

```java
@Data
@Entity
class Parent {
...
    @OneToMany
    private List<Child> children;  // owning side
...
}

@Data
@Entity
class Child {
...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(...)
    @ToString.Exclude            // excludes this field from toString
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude   // excludes this field from equals & hashCode
    private Parent parent;
...
}
```

This way we keep the expected behaviour of:

- including the children's state when the parent's `toString`, `hashCode` & `equals` methods are called
- only taking into account the child's state when calling the child's `toString`, `hashCode` & `equals`

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue by override three method `hashCode` ,`toString`, `equals` in entity A

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    //something
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    //something
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    //something
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Do Not use Lombok with JPA Entity. The toString() goes on Infinite loop.

Other ways, override the toString of Many Entity to return "".

Comment: You can specify which fields to use in `toString` or exclude specific fields with `@lombok.ToString.Exclude` annotation so that it does not go on infinite loop anymore.